# IE link background image doesn't work

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, background-image

Hi I am trying to add background image to my link. The image contains two states, 
A and A:hover.

`a->background-position:bottom` and `a:hover=>background-position:top`. It works fine in chrome and firefox but IE sucks so bad and display total height of the images (two states together). I was wondering if anyone know how to fix it. Thanks..

Html

```
<ul id="menu">

 <li id="dummy"><a href="#"></a></li> 
 <li id="skill"><a href="#"></a></li>

</ul>
```

my css

```
#menu #skill a
{
background-image:url("BTskill.png") ;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:bottom; 
list-style-type:none ;
display:block;
width:98px;
height:18px;
margin-top:5px;
}



#menu #skill a:hover
{
background-image:url("BTskill.png") ;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
list-style-type:none ;
display:block;
width:98px;
height:18px;
background-position: top;  // the image position would change if user hovers the button
margin-top:5px;

}
```

Update:
   I just found out if I take out of a in my css

```
   #menu #skill
    {
    background-image:url("BTskill.png") ;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:bottom; 
    list-style-type:none ;
    display:block;
    width:98px;
    height:18px;
    margin-top:5px;
    }
```

This image would show the correct height, but it is not a link anymore..:(.. man..I hate IE so freaking much...

Comment: Just based on past experience, I would say try the following: background-position should have two things such as "top left"; define a background-color, it can even be "background-color:transparent;". I hope that helps.

Comment: What version of IE? Also, in CSS, a few things: **1)** You don't need to specify 2 IDs, ever, as long as you keep it consistent (`#skill a`, not `#menu #skill a`) **2)** On a `:hover` you only need to list the changes, not everything again. Meaning you can just put the `background-position:top` there.

Comment: :( no luck when giving top left. Thanks thought.

Comment: good tip Kerry, but still no luck after following your direction. Thanks though.

Comment: did you try adding 'background-color:transparent;' ?

Comment: I just update the contents...anyone would help me about it?

Comment: thanks revil, background-color:transparent doesn't work either..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need all the duplicated css for a start.

try:

```
#menu #skill a
{
background-image: url(BTskill.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left bottom;
display: block;
width: 98px;
height: 18px;
margin-top: 5px;
}

#menu #skill a:hover
{
    background-position: left top;
}
```

make sure the hover selector is after the non hover state in your css, you can always try adding a `!important` to the end.

also try giving the `a` some content, like an `&nbsp;`